# Application Icon doesn't change correctly using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I changed my Application's icon for a new one, by going to: "Project/MyProject Properties/Icon and Manifiest", and load the new icon. Now, in my debug folder the icon of my .exe file appear with the new icon, which is ok, but when I execute the .exe, the application icon in the taskbar still showing the old one.

Please advice.

Comment: make sure its .ico and also clean the solution and build it again.

Comment: Do you mean the icon of the executable file or the icon of your window form?
There is a difference between that.

Comment: make sure your form is using the new icon, too.

Comment: if you are loading it from disk and not add resource, make sure you 'copy on build'.

Comment: rebuild all and also make sure running in the right configuration. as in Debug or release

Comment: Hello @DOTNETBEE, it didn't work :(

Comment: The Windows version matters a great deal.  Check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132668

Comment: Yes I mean the icon of the executable file, and when the program is executed, the icon that appears in the taskbar should be the same that the one of the .exe file, and it doesn't

Comment: @Somebody have you checked the icon of your main form?

Comment: @username is blank (no icons there)

Comment: Hello every1 I have another app with the same icon that I want and works perfect, the only difference is that the one in which the icon doesn't show correctly has a deploy project attached to it (created with the old icon) could be that the problem?

Comment: Maybe also related is [this answer in Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/271881/146810), although the answer is focussed on the icon in the task bar - but I think it is the same kind of issue.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have two place to change your icon.

#### First place

The first place is in the project.

1. Right click on the project
2. Select Property
3. Go in Application Tabs
4. Choose Icon and Manifest and select the icon you want

[image]

#### Second place

The second place is in the property of your Winform.

1. Open the Form
2. Click on the Form
3. Press F4 or go in the property of the Form
4. Go down in the property to find "Icon"
5. Select the icon you want.

[image]

The reason you have a different icon in the taskbar than your application (.exe) icon is that the taskbar use the current form icon to display in the taskbar.

Comment: Thanks for respond @Daok, I just want the icon in the taskbar, that's way I don't use icons in the forms.

Comment: even if I put the icon in the form, it still showing the old one when I execute the .exe file :(

Comment: It start to show the correct icon after restart the computer, weird

Answer (score 48):

After encountering the same problem, I resolved it by doing the following:

Just stop your explorer.exe from task manager and rerun the explorer.exe again.

Comment: Looks like updating the icon as shown in the above answer should correctly change them, but as you listed, explorer appears to cache the old icon sometimes.

Comment: weird solution ,but it works !... i guess the explorer does cache the icons (at least on win 10 x64).

Comment: Great idea, @pan4321. This was also the solution for me. I added my program to the task bar but the icon didn't change after replacing it in both places as Patrick mentioned (which is correct) and recompiling it. But after the Explorer restart, it got replaced in the task bar.

Comment: thanks. it worked. I found that if i just rename the icon or copy my exe to some other folder it shows the correct icon

Answer (score 2):

As a commenter mentioned, you should set in the properties of the *.ico file: Copy to Output Dir: Copy if newer.

This property is not absolutely required. I developed a winform application and tested it without icon. Then I created and added the icon. The icon showed when running with the VS debugger. I copied the bin/debug directory to another pc and there it ran with showing the icon.

But the icon did not show on the development machine when the app started by clicking the *.exe file.

Logout/login windows did not cure this.

Change the Copy To Output Dir property on the icon file to Copy If Newer, and rebuild the application, did help. Now I can start the app by clicking the *.exe and the icon shows nicely.

Conclusion:

It is not always required to build the app with the icon file copied to the output  directory, but with this measure you will increase your chances.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, try restarting the Windows Explorer process:

1. Open task manager.
2. Right click at Windows Explorer process
3. Click restart

[image: Task manager]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your *.ico file contains an icon of the proper size (like 16x16 for small task bars).

Comment: Hello Wiktor, I have another app with the new icon, and everything is ok, so the icon size is not the problem.

Comment: If the correct icon size is not found then Windows will created on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for icon information and sizes it supports. Assuming this is just a simple error that you are getting check if your ico's are as per what is specified here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your new icon in Project Properties --> resources --> icons
2. In your `Main_Load` function add:

   ```
   this.Icon = Properties.Resources.newIcon;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the above solved it.
In my case, I had defined the icon different for two different langages (default language english and german). You can see this if there appear two resources files: `FormX.resx` and `FormX.de.resx`

With the accepted answer only default icon was changed. But when running the application on my pc the german icon was used.

So I had to change the icon for both resources. In Visual Studio you can change the current resource language by switching the language item (in the forms properties) from default to another language.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The "first place" mentioned by Patrick is about the file icon, i.e. the .exe aspect. The "second place" is about the form (in the upper left corner).
Restarting windows file explorer seemed to be a satisfactory solution too. But all this didn't work today. I didn't restart the computer, by the way.
This is what really displayed the new icon in the task bar: I realized that there was an old shortcut of the .exe on the desktop. Deleting the shortcut did the job.