# How do I add an icon to Windows Form in SharpDevelop?

Tags: c#, winforms, ide, sharpdevelop

I have already added an icon to the '.exe' file from the Properties Menu in SharpDevelop.

But how do I add an icon to the Windows Form (at top-right in the title bar)?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Form what I remember (it's been about 5 years). Select form, then in properties view find the "Icon" property and select one. I seem to remember it will sow drop down which includes selecting same one as application icon

Comment: there is only Application Icon option

Comment: All winforms `Form`s has [`Icon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.icon.aspx) property. Does this ide has designer? Look for that form property or set icon it in code behind.

Comment: [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560381/application-icon-doesnt-change-correctly-using-c-sharp) it is Visual Studio but should be similar to help you find it. Notice it is a "properties" window, not the project/application properties screen. You ever need help with SharpDevelop then lookup how to do it in VS, they have very similar interfaces.

Comment: @musefan See the pic i just added

Comment: How do you create form in this IDE? Are there **form properties**? There you should find `Icon`. IDE-independent solution is to set `Icon` in code behind (in form constructor, after `InitializeComponents()` to override what was set there).

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: @user3188978: Click on `"MainForm.cs"` (assuming that is the form you want). Click on "Designer" mode (so you get the visual UI designer). Click on the form so it is selected/active. In the "Properties" window (down the right hand side of you current screenshot. Find the "Icon" property. Change that to select your icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharpDevelop has a designer for Windows Forms. Open MainForm.cs, and at the bottom of the text editor there should be a Design tab.

[image]

Click the Design tab to open the forms designer.

Then you can select the form, right click select Properties and then in the Properties window you can set the Icon for the form.

[image]

[image]