# .NET application caches old Icons

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After i changed the Icon of my application, the old Icon is still visible in windows explorer.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. I created a new console application (.NET Framework 4.5.2)
2. I changed the Icon to "1.ico" and build the project

The application has the correct icon:
[image: 1]]

3. After that I changed the icon to "2.ico" and rebuild the project

The application Icon is still the old one:
[image: 2]]

Now the curious thing. When I change the view of windows explorer (with CTRL+Scrollling), the new Icon is visible on a larger view. When I change back to detail view, the old Icon is shown again:
[image: 3]]

I am not sure if it is a problem with .NET, Visual Studio or windows. Does anyone has the same issues?

**I use:**
Windows 10 (latest update)
Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.7)

PS: Yes, I use clover as windows explorer but with the original explorer I have the same problem.

Comment: And you're *sure* the icon only contains the 2? An icon file can contain bitmaps for various resolutions. It isn't as simple as the icon file containing smaller bitmaps with the 1 and larger bitmaps with the 2?

Comment: I think your problem is caused by the Windows icon cache, nothing specific to .NET/ Visual Studio. Have you tried to [clear your cache](https://superuser.com/q/499078/875713)?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I created these two Icons with Paint. There is nothing but the number and white background. In my main application I have an Icon with different sizes (16x16, 32x32 and 64x64) but it is always the same image.

Comment: @quanik Thanks for the link. I cleared the cache but it didn't work.

Comment: @MadMax I could reproduce the scenario you described (using Windows 10 1803, VS 15.8.7) and `ie4uinit.exe -show` did work for me.

Comment: @quanik After a restart the Icon was shown correctly. Don't know why a restart was necessary, but now it is working. Thank you!

Comment: This behavior persists since Windows 98. Clear windows icon cache like most installers do after changing file icons/associated apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application Icon doesn't change correctly using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560381/application-icon-doesnt-change-correctly-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

i got same issue, and i found this:

on Windows, press [Windows Key] + [R] , then Run Window appear,
insert: **ie4uinit -show**  to the field and press enter.

now open Windows Explorer and check if the cache were cleared.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me, answered by ice thailand [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75847789/15016928), was to restart explore.exe. His/her answer shows how to do that if you need assistance.